# Macularian series for natural log

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

So, I know that

$$ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + ... $$

Am I right in assuming that I can derive to follow by a subtitution of $-x$

$$ln(1-x) = -x - \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} - ... $$

This can be useful in telescoping certain infinite sums

In addition to this, are there any other tricks that you know of for telescoping infinite series ( not just for ln, also sin, e, cosh, tanh etc.)

Comment: Something vaguely optical about Macularian...

Comment: Check the interval of convergence

Answer (score 1):

Since the series for $\ln (1+x)$ is valid for all $|x|<1,$ it is certainly valid to replace $x$ with $-x$ when $|x|<1.$ If you like, just write the series for  $\ln (1+y),$ with $|y|<1,$ and let $y=-x.$

One telescoping example is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n(n+1)= (1/1-1/2)+(1/2-1/3)+(1/3-1/4)+... =1.$ That is,more cautiously, $\sum_{n=1}^K 1/n(n+1)=1-1/(K+1).$